# Cardinalities and bijections (naive set theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Note that a set $A$ is said to be **extremely infinite** iff for each set $a$ : $|A\cup\{a\}| = |A|$.

> Let $\alpha$ be a set.
>  Prove that if $\alpha$ is extremely
> infinite, then there exists some $\beta \subset \alpha$ (in particular
> $\alpha \neq \beta$) s.t $|\alpha| \leq |\beta|$

Since we should define such an injective and we only know that one property about $\alpha$, I assume that I just don't see it. I tried to use a diagram to simplify the problem however it just made it more vague.

Wish to get some orientation, thanks.

Comment: How is $\vert X \vert = \vert Y \vert$ defined?

Comment: There exists a bijection $f: X \rightarrow Y$

Comment: In your first line, is little "a" itself an element of A? If not where does it come from?

Comment: $a$ is just some set. I will clarify it, thanks.

Comment: Is your definition supposed to be $∀a. \vert A ∪ a \vert = \vert A \vert$? As you have it now, the natural numbers appear extremely infinite.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Since $\beta \subset \alpha$, we already know that $|\alpha|≥|\beta|$, right?   So you are trying to prove that $|\alpha|=|\beta|$?

Comment: @DanDoel That's just a name so we can talk about the property

Comment: @lulu That is correct

Comment: Can't you just take an $a$ which isn't in $\alpha$ (e.g. $\alpha$), take the bijection $f:\alpha\cup\{a\}\to \alpha$ and then set $\beta$ as the image of $\alpha$ under $f$?

Comment: Note that the statement you are proving does not need $\alpha$ to be extremely infinite, any infinite $\alpha$ will do.  You can follow the same proof with $a$ being a singleton.  $\beta$ is just a strict subset of $\alpha$ with the same cardinality.

Comment: As far as I can see, this definition of extremely infinite is just infinite modulo ZFC?  I never heard "extremely infinite" before, I just used the definition provided by OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take some $a$ with $a\notin\alpha$, e.g. $\alpha$ itself.  Then you get a bijection $f:\alpha\cup\{a\}\to\alpha$ by $\alpha$ being extremely infinite.  Set $\beta:=f[\alpha]$, which is a proper subset since it doesn't contain $f(a)$.  By restricting $f$ to $\alpha$, you get a bijection between $\alpha$ and $\beta$, hence $|\alpha|\le|\beta|$.

Comment: +1, although "e.g. $\alpha$ itself" relies on some axiom. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity

Comment: OK fair, but what can you use, when you don't use axioms?  Can you use that $\alpha$ can't be $V$ (set universe) because $V$ is a proper class?

Comment: Yes I was thinking to this, which makes the previous axiom unnecessary. But implicitely, to not obscure your solution.

Comment: @fweth: Yes, as you say, we know $A$ can’t be $V$, so there must be some set not in it.  And this points us (via Russell’s paradox) to a way to find a specific set that’s not in $A$, without assuming regularity: take $R := \{ x \in A \mid x \notin x \}$.  This is a set (by separation), but it can’t be in $A$, since if it was then we would have $R \in R \Leftrightarrow R \notin R$.

Comment: Yes, but for both arguments, that $\alpha\notin\alpha$ and that $\alpha\neq V$ you need some axiom.  There are set theories like [NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations) which contain a universal set (which also contains itself), so it's a bit hard for me to answer naive set theory questions, since I don't know what exactly is the common ground.